# Как сделать фоксу закладки?

Tags: браузер

В 89.0 версии Firefox сделали всё круглое. Круглое - и ладно. Можно ли на панели сделать закладки а не кнопки, и можно ли вернуть старую высоту, т.к. мало того что кнопки, так ещё и двойной высоты? Возможно как-то через about:config получится? И фидбек как у фокса? На троечку? Не нашёл куда им писать. Есть английский чат... правда поймут ли они на ломаном английском...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: browser.proton.enabled присвоить false.

Comment: Другие параметры, содержащие proton тоже можно в false установить

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/news/t/560642/ - в комментах много советов

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  `browser.proton.enabled` помогло. Никогда бы не догадался что это так называется)))

Comment: Эх, вышла 91-я версия где browser.proton.enabled уже не помагает(

Comment: Угу :(. Теперь все советы сводятся к настройкам в userchrome.css.

Comment: О, новая версия 106 версия ещё левую закеладку впихнула(, Возникает желание вернуть версию и выключитьб автоапдейты надолго)))